# Use the camera on the emulator

Tags: android-emulator

i'm working on an application that needs to capture images with the camera and work on them. Since I no longer have a real android phone to test it I wonder if there is a way to give an image to the emulator (that, obviously, just cannot take a photo and shows only a "chess" background) to make it think that the image is something captured by the camera (then it can show it on the background and not the chess image).
I've seen that there is a way to use a web cam to do this but I don't have any so I might only use it as a last resort.
Thank you for the help